# How to get SVF models?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I want to get an svf model to load a model by svf, but I don’t know how to implement it. I searched about it on the Internet, but found nothing useful. Could you tell me how I can get svf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, after the model is translated to svf successfully you will need to the download all the derivatives present in the manifest (use [GET manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/)) and preserve their relative folder structure - they can sit in whatever parent/root paths so long as the relative paths of the resources are preserved and do watch out for CORS issues when served across different domains.

We do have an online tool for this exact purpose: https://extract.autodesk.io

If you’d like code samples then you won’t need to look further than:  https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io